# R Shiny change config file location

Tags: r, configuration, shiny-server

We are installing R Shiny on a LAMP slice (CentOS) and the default location for the shiny-server.conf file in /etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf doesn't work. All app information for the slice needs to be contained in /hosts/slice73/.

Is there a way to specify where the server conf file should be located during the build process? Here is the error log when we try to start the server.

[2018-01-30 10:23:37.246] [INFO] shiny-server - Using pidfile /hosts/slice73/var/run/shiny-server.pid

[2018-01-30 10:23:37.247] [INFO] shiny-server - Using config file "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf"

[2018-01-30 10:23:37.272] [ERROR] shiny-server - Error loading config: File "/etc/shiny-server/shiny-server.conf" does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is definitely too late for you, I stumbled across the same problem today while trying run shiny-server as a non-root user with a locally compiled version.

Apparently the first argument to shiny-server is the config file.

```
shiny-server path/to/config.conf --pidfile=path/to/pidfile
```

This is as far as I am so far, still running into problems, will try to remember to update this answer, as I find out more. :-)

In the config file i had to explicitly define a bookmark_state_dir, as the default is somewhere in /var/lib

```
bookmark_state_dir path/bookmark/state/dir;
```